# Trying to open a .ini file but i keep getting an error in C#

Tags: c#, file, ini

I'm new to coding so be nice. I'm trying to open a .ini file in a program, but I keep getting this error when I do so.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

My code:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog o1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        o1.Filter = "INI File |*.ini";
        if (o1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            INIFile ini = new INIFile(o1.FileName);
            string reini = ini.Read ("Profile Settings", "User ID");
            int i = int.Parse(reini);
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = i.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = i.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = i.ToString();
            string rechini = ini.Read("Startup", "Check");
            if(rechini == "checked")
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }
       }
   }

}
```

Then the `int i = int.parse(reini);` gets marked in green

Comment: Could you show your INI file, in particular the value of the User ID key.

Comment: What implementation of INIFile is that? It is not a standard .NET class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User ID is most probably an alphanumeric string. You'd be safer with `.TryParse()` in case user ID can be both of alphanumeric and integer types.

```
int i = -1;
string user_id = string.Empty;
if (!int.TryParse(reini, out i))
{
    user_id = reini;
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user_id)) // it is an alphanumeric
{
}
else // it is an integer, use i
{
}
```

**UPDATE**
Since your User ID is a string, just go with  a  string:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog o1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        o1.Filter = "INI File |*.ini";
        if (o1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            INIFile ini = new INIFile(o1.FileName);
            string user_id = ini.Read ("Profile Settings", "User ID");
            textBox1.Text = user_id;
            textBox3.Text = user_id;
            textBox4.Text = user_id;
            textBox5.Text = user_id;
            string rechini = ini.Read("Startup", "Add To Startup");
            if(rechini == "checked")
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }
       }
   }

}
```

**UPDATE2**

There is no `Check` key in your `Startup` INI file section. The code above is updated. There is `Add To Startup`, I guess you need this one.

Comment: this is the content of the .ini file i want to spread out on 4 text boxes

http://gyazo.com/539bcffa565c23356a86ba165461d0f8

Comment: And it is clear that User ID is a string, not an int. Perhaps, you just do not need any parsing to integer? Why not go with a string variable?

Comment: thank you stribizhev, now i need to fix the check boxes and a combobox. i have one combo box and 5 check boxes.

Comment: thank you for your help. I also noticed a typo in my code for the saving part of the .ini file. I wrote "sartup" instead of "Startup"

Comment: now i need to add all the other checkboxes and a combo box. Anyone who can help?

Comment: I'd advise you to use this post answers as a guide. Or when you come into concrete issues, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As stribizhev said, in these cases, TryParse is better than Parse.

This is especially true as your User ID is a string of characters - not a number.

Also, 'Startup' 'checked' will always fail because the setting is named 'Add To Startup' (unless you will have another setting named 'checked' that is not in the file you supplied).

So, change to:

```
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog o1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        o1.Filter = "INI File |*.ini";
        if (o1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            INIFile ini = new INIFile(o1.FileName);
            string reini = ini.Read("Profile Settings", "User ID");
            textBox1.Text = reini;
            textBox3.Text = reini;
            textBox4.Text = reini;
            textBox5.Text = reini;
            string rechini = ini.Read("Startup", "Add To Startup");
            checkBox1.Checked = rechini == "checked";
       }
   }
```